# Using realloc to double an arrays size during runtime. Is my code correct?

Tags: c, realloc

I am unsure if I am using the realloc function correctly.

In my program, I first ask the user for the size of the array and allocate memory for it using malloc, then initialise it with some values.

Then I want to make the same array twice it's size, using realloc. Here is my code. Am I using realloc to resize int *A correctly?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
  int n;
  printf("Enter size of array\n");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  int *A = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));     //dynamically allocated array
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)               //assign values to allocated memory
  { 
    A[i] = i + 1;
  }

  A = (int*)realloc(A, 2*sizeof(int));     //make the array twice the size
  free(A);
}
```

Comment: `2*sizeof(int)` means: the size of 2 ints

Comment: You need `2 * n * sizeof(int)`

Comment: `B` is a *pointer*, so `if (B != NULL) {...}`

Comment: ah ofcourse, silly mistake

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin if(B != 0) is also valid. Also if(B)

Comment: `if(B != 0)` works, but technically violates type comparison as the default type for `0` is `int` and `B` is (or was before the edit) `int *`. Most compilers are smart enough to handle it without warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- When using `malloc()` , don't cast the return value [as said here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/3512538)
- You are not using the right size. In here`int *A = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));` the size given to `malloc` is `n*sizeof(int)`. If you want twice that size, you should call `realloc()` with `n*sizeof(int)*2` instead of `2*sizeof(int)`
- Handle `realloc()` failure. In case `realloc(A, new_size)` fails, `A == NULL` and you will have memory leak. So, use a different pointer `B`, check `if (B != NULL)` and then assign `A = B` (old_size = new_size). If `B == NULL` deal with the allocation fail

Comment: And third bullet: • You should not use the notation `old_ptr = realloc(old_ptr, new_size);` because it leaks memory when `realloc()` fails.  Use `void *new_ptr = realloc(old_ptr, new_size); if (new_ptr != 0) { old_ptr = new_ptr; old_size = new_size; } else { …deal with memory allocation failure… }`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'll add this, but did you intentionally use _void*_ instead of OP _int*_?

Comment: Yes (it was intentional), but using `int *` also works.  Since `realloc()` returns a `void *`, assigning to a `void *` is hardly a crime — it defers the type conversion to the assignment.  Using `int *new_ptr = realloc(…)` does the type conversion with the return value.  Both are valid; use whichever you prefer.

Comment: @Lendl you are now using the right size, but you're still casting: _int *A = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));_

Comment: fixed that as well.

Answer (score 1):

In this case it's easier to double the n before malloc so you don't have the use realloc, because you know, that you gonna double the arraysize. Using realloc can slow the working of the program, because if you make it longer, and the adresses after the currently allocated memories aren't free, then the whole array will be moved. Also you have the change the last line as it was suggested before me.

Comment: I am only using it to understand how to use it in the future.

Comment: By the last line, do you mean free(A)? What is wrong with this?

Comment: Sorry saying last line was wrong, I meant to say the line of realloc. Although now it looks fine for me.